# How to install ipython in Debian 12 or Ubuntu 23.04 where pip3 prevents installation due to "externally-managed-environment"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, python-venv, debian-bookworm

`python3` is a system wide program, just as `pip3` is.

I want to install `ipython` on Debian 12. (This info also relevant to newer Ubuntu versions, since these are derived directly from Debian and contain the same policy change.)

I would probably expect this to also be a system-wide available program, just like `python3` and `pip3`. Please correct me if that no longer makes sense given the recent changes which prevent (by default) users from installing `pip3` packages system wide, instead encoraging the use of `venv`s.

Previously I would have run `pip3 install ipython`. What should I now do instead?

Error message when attempting to run `pip3 install ipython`.

```
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.

    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.

    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.

    See /usr/share/doc/python3.11/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
```

Comment: Use virtual environment, or pipx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual solution I used, thanks to others for directing me to `venv`.

```
python3 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate # do this every time to use the venv created above
pip3 install ipython
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 install --user ipython
```

But before you much further, search te internet and learn about "virtual enviroment" for Python.

Comment: Does `--user` do the same as creating a `venv`, then installing `ipython` in that `venv`? I am just learning about these now. I assume there must be somewhere a default global `venv` which commands like this operate on?

Comment: no. It installs packages in a subfolder of  `~/.local/...`  which is also on your Python search path, with a higher precedence than the system folders. And also, is user-writable, so no need for "sudo". It won't conflict with your system packages, but also won t allow you to have different library versions across your projects: it would be better  to have an explicit virtual env anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [PEP 668](https://peps.python.org/pep-0668/#guide-users-towards-virtual-environments) , you can create a new virtual environment to install `ipython` (or any other python package in your system) or use `pipx`.

To install pipx, run:

```
sudo apt install pipx -y
pipx ensurepath
```

Install the package from PyPI, like this:

```
pipx install ipython
```

reload your terminal, and check your installation:

```
ipython --version
```